# Is there a library which provides utility functions for views based on twitter bootstrap for play framework

Tags: scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0

Play framework (2.0 onwards) with scala provides a good opportunity for composing user interface in terms of reusable components or functions. On the other hand Twitter Bootstrap provides tons of utility components for a standard html5 user interface.

Is there any open source library available with wraps the twitter bootstrap components and exposes them as reusable functions via play templates (or scalate may be?), this will save a lot of time in hand coding the html markup.

Comment: I am not aware of it, but it is an excellent idea to start ;-) +1 as a volounteer!

Comment: I'm currently working on that. I can join and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play2 includes support for old bootstrap version - but this won't help you a lot, really. After some trial and error one manages to integrate Play2 and Bootstap3 pretty nicely using Play2 form helpers and implicit contructors (@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ helper.FieldConstructor(*your-scala-template-here*.render), but result will be very project dependent.

My notes of issue are here http://nikkijuk.blogspot.de/2013/10/play2-forms-and-bootstrap.html

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, It is helpful. how ever my thoughts were about another level of abstraction something like @form.toBootStrapForm('action="/action",'class="form-horizontal") and it should take care of all the elements, layout, markup etc. Also not only form but all other elements like navbar or tables

Comment: Hi skywalker. I really liked this example. Now as it's updated to Play 2.2 and Bootstrap 3 it might give you good ideas. http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-form/